# How do i dynamically create JSX tag in React using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dynamic, import, react-icons

I want to import [react-icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons) dynamically.

This works in Javascript, but how do i convert this to Typescript without getting all sorts of errors?

**Code:**

```
import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/all';
const getIcon = (icon) => {
  const TagName = ReactIcons[icon];
  return <TagName />;
};
```

Here is output from .d.ts files from react-icons if that helps:

```
// node_modules/react-icons/all.d.ts
export * from './fa';
export * from './fa';
export * from './io';
export * from './md';
export * from './ti';
export * from './go';
export * from './fi';
export * from './gi';
export * from './gi';
export * from './gi';
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like:

```
import * as ReactIcons from 'react-icons/all';

type GetIconProps = {
  icon: keyof typeof ReactIcons;
}

const getIcon = ({icon}: GetIconProps) => {
  const TagName = ReactIcons[icon];
  return <TagName />;
};

// Example
getIcon({icon: keyof typeof ReactIcons})
```

Or even shorter:

```
const getIcon = ({ icon }: GetIconProps) => {
  const TagName = ReactIcons[icon];
  return <TagName />;
};
```

Must say it feels a bit hacky though, so would try to import straight from the package instead.